# Out-File to Network share, written as hostname.txt

Tags: powershell

I need to `out-file` the results of the script to a network share `\\prod-automation\exampledir` and I want to recursively remove IIS logs that are older than 30 days, but not the folders.

Here is what I have:

```
$WhatIfPreference = $true
$file = ("$($env:computername)$($Filename).txt")
$Directory = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles*"
Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse | Sort-Object Name, LastWriteTime | Format-Table Name, Fullname, LastWriteTime | out-file $file -filepath "\\\PROD-AUTOMATION\PowerShellLogs\IIS_Cleanup" -noclobber
$logpath = "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\"
Get-ChildItem $logpath -recurse *.log -force | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get- date).adddays(-0)} | Remove-Item -force
```

The current issue is that I get the following:

```
Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "PROD-CONTOSCO.txt" does not belong to the set   "unicode,utf7,utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
```

Need some assistance getting this going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$file = "$env:computername$Filename.txt"
....
out-file -filepath "\\PROD-AUTOMATION\PowerShellLogs\IIS_Cleanup\$filepath" -noclobber
```

Comment: Will try in the morning. Thank you. =]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for this. Learned a lesson!

Comment: I assume you meant `$file` and `$filepath` to be the same. I'd edit but less than 6 character edits are rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this line:

```
out-file -filepath $("\\PROD-AUTOMATION\PowerShellLogs\IIS_Cleanup\" + $filepath) -noclobber
```

Comment: Out-File : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Almost there. I should say that the path is verified and I can access it.

Comment: For future readers, I had an extra `\` in the answer, that's where the error above came from.